# Do we release an argument in fast enumeration

Tags: objective-c, loops, fast-enumeration

do we release an argument in fast enumeration? Therefore would this code be accurate:

```
    for (MKCircle *circle in localOverlays) {

    [mapView addOverlay: circle];

    [circle release]; // Is it perfectly alright to call this?
}
```

I am just wondering, my first time working with fast enumeration!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the [Apple Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

> - You own any object you create
>
>   You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”

Did you create `circle`? No.

> You can take ownership of an object using retain

Did you retain `circle`? No.

So you don't own the object.

> You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own

That seems fairly straight forward now that you have determined you don't own `circle`.  The release in the example code in your question should not be there.  In fact, most likely, it will cause a crash somewhere down the line.

Comment: This was the most comprehensive and detailed for a 13 year old kid... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Fast enumeration does not *usually* create new objects, it is going through the existing ones. That is why it is almost never the right thing to do: fast enumeration of regular containers (`NSArray`, `NSSet`, `NSDictionary`) does not retain objects before making them available to the loop, so releasing them would be an error. Even inside a `dealloc` method you shouldn't do it: releasing the container releases its items too, so you shouldn't be releasing them individually.

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think it's the right thing to do.  It neither do a `retain` nor a `release` to the instance

```
for (MKCircle *circle in localOverlays) {

    [mapView addOverlay: circle]; //retain here
}
```

addOverley: should do a retain to `circle`, and it's mapView's responsibility to `release` when mapView doesn't needs it

Simple guide, you `retain` it, and `release` it when you done using it